# Phonegap: How can I implement this chunk of code?

Tags: html, css, cordova, web, phonegap-build

I found this neat animation that I want to implement inside a Phonegapp application. **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKNpOa?editors=0100**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Computer World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Gooey Menu</h1>
<h2>Using CSS and SVG Filters</h2>
<h3>By <a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber">Lucas Bebber</a></h3>
<h4><a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/LELBEo" target="_blank">Version 1</a> - Version 2 - <a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp" target="_blank">Version 3</a> - <a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/rawQKR" target="_blank">Version 4</a></h4>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open"/>
  <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-1"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-2"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-3"></span>
  </label>

  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> </a>

</nav>


<!-- filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="shadowed-goo">

          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feGaussianBlur in="goo" stdDeviation="3" result="shadow" />
          <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 -0.2" result="shadow" />
          <feOffset in="shadow" dx="1" dy="1" result="shadow" />
          <feComposite in2="shadow" in="goo" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
      <filter id="goo">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import "compass/css3";

//vars
$fg:#e91e63;
$bg:#8bc34a;
$pi:3.14;

//config
$menu-items:6+1;
$open-distance:105px;
$opening-angle:$pi*2;

body{
  background:$bg;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
a{
  color:inherit;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4{
  margin:0;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
h1{
  font-size:3em;
}
%goo{
  filter:url('#goo');
  // debug 
  // background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
%ball{
  background:$fg;
  border-radius:100%;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  margin-left:-40px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:80px;
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  transition:transform ease-out 200ms;
}
.menu-open{
  display:none;
}
.menu-item{
  @extend %ball;
}
.hamburger{
  $width:25px;
  $height:3px;
  width:$width;
  height:$height;
  background:white;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-$width/2;
  margin-top:-$height/2;
  transition:transform 200ms;
}
$hamburger-spacing:8px;
.hamburger-1{
  transform:translate3d(0,-$hamburger-spacing,0);
}
.hamburger-2{
  transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.hamburger-3{
  transform:translate3d(0,$hamburger-spacing,0);
}
.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button{
  .hamburger-1{
    transform:translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(45deg); 
  }
  .hamburger-2{
    transform:translate3d(0,0,0) scale(0.1,1);
  }
  .hamburger-3{
    transform:translate3d(0,0,0) rotate(-45deg); 
  }
}
.menu{
  @extend %goo;
  $width:380px;
  $height:250px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-$width/2;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:$width/2;
  width:$width;
  height:$height;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:left;
}


.menu-item{
  &:hover{
    background:white;
    color:$fg;
  }
  @for $i from 1 through $menu-items{
    &:nth-child(#{$i+2}){
      transition-duration:180ms;
    }
  }
}

.menu-open-button{
  @extend %ball;
  z-index:2;
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  transition-duration:400ms;
  transform:scale(1.1,1.1) translate3d(0,0,0);
  cursor:pointer;
}
.menu-open-button:hover{
  transform:scale(1.2,1.2) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.menu-open:checked+.menu-open-button{
  transition-timing-function:linear;
  transition-duration:200ms;
  transform:scale(0.8,0.8) translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.menu-open:checked~.menu-item{
  transition-timing-function:cubic-bezier(0.935, 0.000, 0.340, 1.330);
  @for $i from 1 through $menu-items{
    $angle:(($pi - $opening-angle)/2)+(($opening-angle/($menu-items - 1))*($i - 1));

    &:nth-child(#{$i+2}){
      transition-duration:80ms+(100ms*$i);
      transform:translate3d(cos($angle)*$open-distance,sin($angle)*$open-distance,0);
    }
  }
}
```

I pasted the HTML code in the index.html and the CSS in the index.css but it seems like it's not working.

How can I implement this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a simple thing: you copied the SCSS instead of compiling it to CSS first. So, this works:

```css
body {
  background: #8bc34a;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.menu {
  -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
          filter: url("#goo");
}

.menu-item, .menu-open-button {
  background: #e91e63;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open {
  display: none;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -12.5px;
  margin-top: -1.5px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms;
  transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.hamburger-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.hamburger-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.hamburger-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-1 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}
.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .hamburger-3 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -190px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 190px;
  width: 380px;
  height: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.menu-item:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #e91e63;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}
.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-open-button {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
          transition-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
          transition-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
          transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
          transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
          transition-duration: 180ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 280ms;
          transition-duration: 280ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 380ms;
          transition-duration: 380ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 480ms;
          transition-duration: 480ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 580ms;
          transition-duration: 580ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 680ms;
          transition-duration: 680ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
}
.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 780ms;
          transition-duration: 780ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>Gooey Menu</h1>
<h2>Using CSS and SVG Filters</h2>
<h3>By <a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber">Lucas Bebber</a></h3>
<h4><a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/LELBEo" target="_blank">Version 1</a> - Version 2 - <a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp" target="_blank">Version 3</a> - <a href="http://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/rawQKR" target="_blank">Version 4</a></h4>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="menu">
  <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open"/>
  <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-1"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-2"></span>
    <span class="hamburger hamburger-3"></span>
  </label>
  
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> </a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i> </a>
  
</nav>


<!-- filters -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <filter id="shadowed-goo">
          
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feGaussianBlur in="goo" stdDeviation="3" result="shadow" />
          <feColorMatrix in="shadow" mode="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1 -0.2" result="shadow" />
          <feOffset in="shadow" dx="1" dy="1" result="shadow" />
          <feComposite in2="shadow" in="goo" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
      <filter id="goo">
          <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="10" />
          <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" />
          <feComposite in2="goo" in="SourceGraphic" result="mix" />
      </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```